# Parsing Google Location History in a (SQLite) Database

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am trying to parse the very large JSON file (for me around 100MB, ~4 million lines) that you receive when downloading your personal location history from [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) and put in a local database in an Android application.

The structure of the JSON file looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEw9O.png), and I put a very small sample on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/q4drhtJS) to show the structure.

```
{
    "locations" : [ {
      "timestampMs" : "1518722738911",
      "latitudeE7" : 123456789,
      "longitudeE7" : 123456789,
      "accuracy" : 21
    }, {
      "timestampMs" : "1518722617339",
      "latitudeE7" : 123456789,
      "longitudeE7" : 123456789,
      "accuracy" : 21,
      "activity" : [ {
        "timestampMs" : "1518722603634",
        "activity" : [ {
          "type" : "TILTING",
          "confidence" : 100
        } ]
      }, {
        "timestampMs" : "1518722660455",
        "activity" : [ {
          "type" : "STILL",
          "confidence" : 55
        } ]
      } ]
    } ]
}
```

When parsing this in Java with GSON, you will get a **LinkedTreeMap**. I know that GSON is not the fastest parser out there, but that is another issue.

The purpose of storing all the JSON data into a SQLite database is to have it available much faster and analyze it, so I would like to have the data as practical as possible.

I tried creating two separate tables, one for simple timestamps and their longitude and langitude, and one for the activities associated with timestamps themselves.

However, I can't quite wrap my head around of how to iterate through this TreeMap correctly, converting those entries into simple rows, since it's quite a mess with many subarrays.

Is SQLite even the right datbase, or should I use something else for this kind of data? How would you parse such a file?

Any tip or suggestion is very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You could use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ which converts Json to Pojo automatically.